# How do I convert an asp.net treeview control to ul/li HTML elements?

Tags: html, asp.net, treeview

In asp.net, I have a treeview control that creates the following HTML elements:

```
<div id="MainContent_TreeView1">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td><a id="MainContent_TreeView1n0" ></a></td><td ><a class="MainContent_TreeView1_0" id="MainContent_TreeView1t0">node1</a></td>
        </tr>
    </table><div id="MainContent_TreeView1n0Nodes" >
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td><div style="width:20px;height:1px"></div></td><td><a class="MainContent_TreeView1_0" >node1-1</a></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div><table>
        <tr>
            <td><a id="MainContent_TreeView1n2"></a></td><td ><a class="MainContent_TreeView1_0" id="MainContent_TreeView1t2">node2</a></td>
        </tr>
    </table><div id="MainContent_TreeView1n2Nodes" >
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td><div style="width:20px;height:1px"></div></td><td></td><td ><a class="MainContent_TreeView1_0"  id="MainContent_TreeView1t3">node2-1</a></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div><table>
        <tr>
            <td></td><td ><a class="MainContent_TreeView1_0"  id="MainContent_TreeView1t4">node3</a></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

However, I need it to generate `ul` and `li` elements instead. How do I do this?